# Serialization: How to Deserialize in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

How can I deserialize the string based on what I have done in this method? Basically, what I have here is to pass the string through the network using serialization and deserialize the string in order to convey the message. But once I managed to receive the message, I have no idea if what I'm doing is correct. Here's the code:

```
string ConvertToString(FrogGame np, Frog1 pm, Frog2 pm2) //Serialization. the three parameters are the classes. 
        {
            XmlSerializer sendSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FrogGame),new Type[]{typeof(Frog1),typeof(Frog2)});
            StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"pad1.xml");
            sendSerializer.Serialize(myWriter, np);
            sendSerializer.Serialize(myWriter, pm);
            sendSerializer.Serialize(myWriter, pm2);
            return myWriter.ToString();
        } //Overall, I serialize it into string
```

Once I pass the string through the network, I want to deserialize it in order the pass the message to the classes. How do I continue here onwards? How can I edit? The code:

```
void StringReceived(string str) //so str is myWriter.ToString()
        {
            XmlSerializer revSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FrogGame), new Type[] { typeof(Frog1), typeof(Frog2) });
            FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(@"pad1.xml", FileMode.Open);
            FrogGame b = (FrogGame)revSerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);

            if (b is Frog1) 
            {
                if (Network.IsServer())
                {
                    pm = (Frog1)b;
                    pm.Position.Y = b.pm.Position.Y;
                    pm.Position.X = b.pm.Position.X;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BAD Message: " + msg);
                }
            }

            else if (b is Frog2)
            {
                if (Network.IsClient())
                {
                    pm2 = (PaddleMessage2)b;
                    pm2.Position.Y = b.pm2.Position.Y;
                    pm2.Position.X = b.pm2.Position.X;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BAD Message: " + msg);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You should use JSON, because XML just creates an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I do heard that JSON is better, but XML serialization is easier for a head start. So just trying out for XML serialization before moving on. So do you know how to input the string to xmlserialiser to deserialize it?

Comment: Why are you serializing to a file when you want to send the string over the network? Use a `StringWriter` instead. Or just use the network stream. Btw, returning `myWriter.ToString()` is probably not what you want. Are you experiencing problems with your code? Have you checked the messages?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Okay. So is it okay to send the whole MyWriter instead?

Comment: No, its not. You should send the string result of the serializer. You can use a `StringWriter` to serialize to a string instead of a file. Then, `ToString()` is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might misinterpret your problem, but I why don't you put all the thing you want to save in a class and do it like this (plus, if you use class, your data "transportation" and "management" will be much easier) :

**SERIALIZATION**

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FrogGameData));
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("FrogGameSaveFile.xml");
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, _frogGameData);
textWriter.Close();
```

**DESERIALIZATION**

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FrogGameData));
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader("FrogGameSaveFile.xml");
_frogGameData = (FrogGameData)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
textReader.Close();
```

**Note :** The need-to-be-saved field should have property, because the tag in the XML will mimic the property name.

**Additional Note :** `FrogGameData` is not different than a normal class for automatic serialization like this. The XML will mimic your property order in the class for the one in the XML file.

But if you wanna need to rearrange the XML tag placement, you could do something like `[XmlElement(Order = 1)]`,`[XmlElement(Order = 2)]`, etc on top of your property to customize the order in XML file.

---

**UPDATE**

In case you need it, this is an example of your FrogGameData class :

```
public class FrogGameData
{
    private Frog _frog1;
    private Frog _frog2;

    public Frog Frog1
    {
        get { return _frog1; }
        set { _frog1 = value; }
    }

    public Frog Frog2
    {
        get { return _frog2; }
        set { _frog2 = value; }
    }
}
```

**And the XML will pretty much like this :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrogGameData>
    <Frog1>Something-depends-on-your-data</Frog1>
    <Frog2>Something-depends-on-your-data</Frog2>
</FrogGameData>
```

**But, if your class is (Note the `XmlElement` part) :**

```
public class FrogGameData
{
    private Frog _frog1;
    private Frog _frog2;

    [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
    public Frog Frog1
    {
        get { return _frog1; }
        set { _frog1 = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    public Frog Frog2
    {
        get { return _frog2; }
        set { _frog2 = value; }
    }
}
```

**Then, your XML will be :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrogGameData>
    <Frog2>Something-depends-on-your-data</Frog2>
    <Frog1>Something-depends-on-your-data</Frog1>
</FrogGameData>
```